# How to set the type of a list during runtime?

Tags: c++, list

I have a class which basically contains a list of events (where event is another class)

```
#include "event.h"
#include <list>

class EventPacket
{

private:
    int max_size;

public:
    std::list<Event> EventList;
    EventPacket();
    ~EventPacket();

    void add(Event *event);
    int size();
    void sort();
    int merge(EventPacket *ep);
    void clear();
};
```

So far this works fine. But now, I have another class SpecialEvent which is an extension of the Event class. I would like to use the same class EventPacket for putting the special events into a list and I'm wondering what's the correct way of doing this? Is there a way of creating a list without defining its type such that the type (in my case event or specialevent) can be set at runtime?

Comment: You will need to store (possibly smart) pointers to `Event` in the list.

Comment: What's the difference between the two kinds of events? If they contain plain data, a pointer to its beginning and the size of the data is probably sufficient to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must store a list of pointers, rather than a list of objects.  For example:

```
std::list<Event*> EventList;
```

or

```
std::list<shared_ptr<Event>> EventList;
```

You cannot store a list of `Event` objects because any inherited objects will become sliced.  Essentially the inherited parts will be cut off.  See: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Because you are storing pointers, you now have a memory management problem.  You must decide whether your `EventPacket` object should take ownership of the objects and then delete them or whether the calling code should delete them.

To solve this, you may want to look into smart pointers, such as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.  The decision you make on ownership semantics will determine whether smart pointers will be useful and if so, which one to choose.

Comment: thanks. so am I correct in understanding that i have to create a new list in the constructor of the EventPacket itself? How do i do that?

    `this->EventList = new std::list<Event*>;`

Comment: No, your list should be a concrete object as you have it now, but the elements it stores must be pointers to objects.

Comment: Works, thanks. For those having problems using shared_ptr with gcc 4.6.3, you have to include `#include <memory>` and compile with `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the chapter in your C++ book about *polymorphism*.

You can't change the list's type at runtime, but if you store pointers in it then you can make use of *virtual dispatch* to have those pointers point to objects of different levels of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the list a list of `Event` pointers; these can point to instances of any class derived from `Event` (including `Event` itself).

I recommend you use a smart pointer class like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to simplify memory management.

Example:

```
list<shared_ptr<Event> > EventList;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation for polymorphism. If you have your class `SpecialEvent` derived from `Event` you can use pointers and determine their behavior dynamically at runtime

```
std::list<Event*> EventList;
```

If you have `virtual` methods, the runtime will pick the right one during runtime. Else you might have to use `dynamic_cast<>` to get the correct type at runtime.

Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) article on `polymorphism`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you pass a pointer to the `add` function, you can store these pointers in the list instead of copies. Preferably a smart pointer such as [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).